# passing values between methods in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cllocation

I'm confused. Read up on a whole lot of resources but it didn't help.
How can I pass a value generated in a method (variable) to another method so it can be used for calculations. I found a post about putting a property in the .h file. Did that.
In my method I called first the methodname and then the variable but it will not work.
This is the code:

```
-(void)recordLocation{

double valueLat = [[latitude text]doubleValue];
int latSeconds = valueLat * 3600;
int latDegrees = latSeconds / 3600;
latSeconds = abs(latSeconds % 3600);
int latMinutes = latSeconds / 60;
latSeconds %= 60;

char latChar = (latitude > 0) ? 'N' : 'S';

double valueLon = [[longitude text]doubleValue];
int lonSeconds = valueLon * 3600;
int lonDegrees = lonSeconds / 3600;
lonSeconds = abs(lonSeconds % 3600);
int lonMinutes = lonSeconds / 60;
lonSeconds %= 60;

char lonChar = (longitude > 0) ? 'E' : 'W';

CLLocation *tempPos = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:valueLat longitude:valueLon]; //tempPos is what I want to pass

NSString *recPosition = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i° %i' %i\" %c" "   " @"%i° %i' %i\" %c \n", latDegrees, latMinutes, latSeconds, latChar,lonDegrees, lonMinutes, lonSeconds, lonChar];

_labelDegrees.text = recPosition;

//NSLog(@"%f" , valueLat);
//NSLog(@"%f" , valueLon);
//NSLog (@"%@", tempPos);



}

- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation{

double lat1 = [[latitude text] doubleValue];
double lon1 = [[longitude text] doubleValue];


CLLocation *currentLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:lon1];

CLLocationDistance locDistance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:recordLocation.tempPos];//tempPos is what I want to use from recordLocation

NSString *distText = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f", locDistance];

//NSLog(@"%f", lat1);
//NSLog(@"%f", lon1);
NSLog(@"%@", currentLocation);
NSLog(@"%@", tempPos);


[lonDistance setText:distText];
}
```

It is the variable tempPos what gives me pain. 
To be as complete as possible, here is my .h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "Corelocation/Corelocation.h"


NSString *latr;
NSString *longr;
NSString *latLabDeg;
NSString *lat;
NSString *lon;
NSString *acc;
double valueLon;
double valueLat;
double latvalue;
double lonvalue;
CLLocation *tempPos;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *accuracy;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *latitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *longitude;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *location;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *latrec;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *longrec;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelDegrees;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *lonDistance;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationDistance *locDistance;
@property (retain) CLLocation *tempPos;

//- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation;
```

Please, can you help me? Right now I feel very stupid because it has to be a simple thing.

Regards,

Adri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your problem is that in your method you are declaring a local variable so you are not working with your instance property.

```
CLLocation *tempPos = ...
```

Change that line to this:

```
tempPos = ...
```

**EDIT:**
Some tips if you want to get that result from outside the method, there are two simple ways:

1) Return that variable. Since your method is a `- (void)...` (isn't returning anything) you could easily add a return variable and `return tempPos;` at the end

2) If in some future you already have a return value but you still want the outside method to have access to what you generated there, you can do this:

```
- (NSInteger)someMethod:(ObjectClassName **)object { // Yes, there are TWO of these > *
    .. work some magic
    ObjectClassName *theObject = ...

    *object = theObject;
    return whatever;
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
ObjectClassName *object = nil;
NSInteger whatever = [self someMethod:&object]; // < this behavior comes from c++
```

Or if you don't care about that variable, like this:

```
NSInteger whatever = [self someMethod:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you! I've tried your reply and it works great. Must say: I thought it would be simple... but so simple? I'm a bit shamed ;). Now I'm gonna work on a conditional AlertView. Wish me luck. THanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, with regard to your headers, you do *not* need to declare the iVar separately from your `@property` declaration. In fact it is best not to. The `@property` declaration will auto-synthesize an iVar and name it with a preceding _underscore.

Then you can then refer to the iVar either directly as `_tempPos` or via it's property `self.tempPos`. You should almost always use the property syntax. This will ensure that you are certain when you are accessing an iVar as opposed to a local variable (the source of your confusion here).

(See my answer to this question to clarify this point:
[Should I declare variables in interface or using property in objective-c arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236799/should-i-declare-variables-in-interface-or-using-property-in-objective-c-arc/14236931#14236931))

Here:

```
CLLocation *tempPos = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:valueLat longitude:valueLon];
```

you are creating a new local variable called `tempPos`

What you intended to do was to assign your new CLLocation to your `temppos` iVar:

```
self.tempPos = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:valueLat longitude:valueLon];
```

Also note the error here:
    @property (retain) CLLocation *tempPos;

This should be *strong*, not retain as you are using ARC.

Answer (score 0):

If your first function returns a value you can simply use that function as the argument for the function that needs to use the value.

Example:

```
[aFunction:[otherFunction]];
```

Specifically for your example, change the function to return isntead of `(void)recordLocation`
to `(CLLocation)recordLocation`

Answer (score 0):

`How can I pass a value generated in a method (variable) to another method so it can be used for calculations.`

```
resultValue=[self secondMethodParameter:[self firstMethodParameter:parameter]];
```

---

You are calling this method :

`CLLocationDistance locDistance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:recordLocation.tempPos];//tempPos is what I want to use from recordLocation`

change it to :

`CLLocationDistance locDistance = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:[self recordLocation]];//tempPos is what I want to use from recordLocation`

and the method as :

```
-(CLLocation *)recordLocation{

   ...

    CLLocation *tempPosLocal = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:valueLat longitude:valueLon]; //tempPos is what I want to pass

    ...

    return tempPosLocal;

}
```

---

I am seeing your following code, return is missing.

```
- (CLLocationDistance)distanceFromLocation{

     ...

     [lonDistance setText:distText];
}
```

Comment: You are right. But how would that solve his issue with his tempPos variable? However, I do not think that he was asking for passing parameters. That would require that one method calls the other.

Comment: Still there is a class property tempPos plus a local variable tempPos. Values stored in tempPos within recordLocation will never ever be in tempPos in his distanceFromLocation where he actually NSLogs the class property.

Comment: if this is the case then compiler will show a warning.. local instance hiding property... then he can change the local variable..

Answer (score 0):

Using a property is quite right. It could be a local property though. However, it should work.

Your mistake is here:

```
CLLocation *tempPos = ...
```

Although there is a property of the same type and name defined you are defining a local (within the method) object of the same type and name. That hides the property.

In principle this is fine - if you ever need to do that. In such a case

```
tempPos = ...
```

would access the local variable while

`self.tempPos = ...`

would access the property (through the setter).

However, you do not need a local variable here. Just change

```
CLLocation *tempPos = ...
```

to

```
self.tempPos = ...
```

and you should be fine.