# Is it ok to just use instance variable and NOT property

Tags: ios

I have an instance variable apiEndpoint that I don't want to be set from anywhere except init and I only want it to be private to the class. Is it ok if I use an instance variable and NOT a property?

ApiWrapper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ApiWrapper : NSObject
{
    NSString *apiEndpoint;
}

- (void) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;


+ (NSString *)getApiEndpoint:(NSString *) storeUrl;
+ (NSString *)getApiEndpointWithoutIndexDotPHP:(NSString *) storeUrl;
@end
```

ApiWrapper.m

```
#import "ApiWrapper.h"


@implementation ApiWrapper
- (void) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;
{
    apiEndpoint = newApiEndpoint;
}
+ (NSString *)getApiEndpoint:(NSString *) storeUrl
{
    if (![storeUrl hasPrefix:@"http://"] && ![storeUrl hasPrefix:@"https://"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ missing http", storeUrl);
    }

    return nil;
}

+ (NSString *)getApiEndpointWithoutIndexDotPHP:(NSString *) storeUrl
{

}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's OK to use ivars. However, what is cool about properties is that they create your getter and setter for you, which are more than just reading or writing a variable value but can include things like object retain management, thread-safe read and writes, and more.

There is a way to make a "private property" by declaring it in an anonymous class extension in your class's .m file. Note you will still have to use the ivar backing the property in the init and dealloc method. Your code would look something like this:

```
#import "ApiWrapper.h"

@interface ApiWrapper ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* apiEndpoint;

@end

@implementation ApiWrapper

- (id) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;
{
    self = [super init]
    if ( self ) {
        _apiEndpoint = newApiEndpoint;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting a Class Extension. Note however that a property declared as just (strong) will be atomic, a nontrivial difference.

Comment: I think for almost all uses properties should be `nonatomic`.

Comment: also, my personal preference is to use properties as much as possible--I almost never use ivar's except in the property getter/setter/dealloc/init.

Comment: @nielsbot yeah ... i've just been doing too much threaded programming lately, got into the habit ... updating answer.

Comment: @nielsbot There is little reason to use properties if they are not public - at least if you are using ARC. In a majority of cases, properties were helpful due to easy memory management. With ARC, this benefit is gone. Unless you have a reason to explicitly implement custom getter/setter methods for a private property, there is no benefit to the property. Public properties are still useful to provide a convenient interface for the class.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with claireware's suggestion to use a private property in your private class extension. Another approach, if you want other classes to be able to see it, but not alter it, is to define it as a read only property:

In ApiWrapper.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ApiWrapper : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *apiEndpoint;

- (id) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;

+ (NSString *)getApiEndpoint:(NSString *) storeUrl;
+ (NSString *)getApiEndpointWithoutIndexDotPHP:(NSString *) storeUrl;

@end
```

And in ApiWrapper.m:

```
#import "ApiWrapper.h"

@interface ApiWrapper ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *apiEndpoint;

@end

@implementation ApiWrapper

- (id) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;
{
    self = [super alloc];
    if (self)
    {
        _apiEndpoint = newApiEndpoint;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Two notes:

1. The `init...` method should not have a `void` return type. `init` methods should always return an initialized object.
2. If you use properties, remember to [Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

---

Obviously, if you really wanted to use an ivar (and I agree with others that you can achieve what you want with a property), it would simply be:

ApiWrapper.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ApiWrapper : NSObject

- (id) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;

+ (NSString *)getApiEndpoint:(NSString *) storeUrl;
+ (NSString *)getApiEndpointWithoutIndexDotPHP:(NSString *) storeUrl;

@end
```

And in ApiWrapper.m:

```
#import "ApiWrapper.h"

@interface ApiWrapper ()
{
    NSString *apiEndpoint;
}
@end

@implementation ApiWrapper

- (id) initWithApiEndpoint:(NSString *) newApiEndpoint;
{
    self = [super alloc];
    if (self)
    {
        apiEndpoint = newApiEndpoint;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

See my answer here:
[Should I declare variables in interface or using property in objective-c arc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236799/should-i-declare-variables-in-interface-or-using-property-in-objective-c-arc/14236931#14236931)

The summary version:

- whenever possible, declare properties
- don't declare iVars separately
- don't @synthesize
- locate as few properties as possible in you .h file
- locate as many properties as possible in a class extension in your .m file

The only other point I would add - if for whatever reason you *are* going to use iVars, *please* use a clear convention like _leading _underscores so that we know what you are doing when we read your code.