# What's the difference the member variable between in a interface and @property (nonatomic, strong)?

Tags: objective-c

```
@interface ChargeView (){
    NSString* billid;
    int clickRow;
    NSMutableArray  *arr1;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arr2;
```

What's the difference between arr1 and arr2? Which is better or write it anywhere if I like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between an "instance variable" and a "property" in Objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843632/is-there-a-difference-between-an-instance-variable-and-a-property-in-objecti)

Comment: Could you search for one of the approximately 100 answers to this question?

Comment: checkout http://stackoverflow.com/a/14236931/1298043

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property also generates the accessors `-(NSMutableArray *)arr2` (getter) and `-(void)setArr2:(NSMutableArray *)arr2` (setter). It further generates a corresponding instance variable `_arr2` (the underscore is convention for ivars). The attributes of the property determine the behavior of the accessors. For instance, if the property is marked `atomic`, the accessors will synchronize access to the ivar.

On the other hand, `arr1` is just an ivar and you have to write accessors (if you need any) yourself.